# Awk print results for regular expression issue

Tags: awk

I am trying to print all of the words followed by a # using awk from a file the code below works on the words that have a space after the word but some of the words do not have a space and it prints the whole line. Is there a way to have the code only print the word in the case where there is no space?

Code used:

```
gawk.exe "{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~ /#[A-Z]*/) {print $i}}" "file.csv"
```

Sample Data:

```
#Realtree #HuntWithAnEDGE #RealtreeEDGE #DeerHunting",https://www.facebook.com/Realtree/photos/a.103244392286/10158628671852287/?
```

My results:

```
#Realtree
#HuntWithAnEdge
#RealtreeEDGE
#DeerHunting",https://www.facebook.com/Realtree/photos/a.103244392286/10158628671852287/?
```

On the last result all I need is `#DeerHunting`

Comment: Edited for you, please take a look at [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)
 for code blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using as much possible your awk:

```
gawk "{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (match($i, /#[a-zA-Z]+/, a)) {print a[0]}}" file
```

But if you have [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), you should have [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) too, so:

```
grep -o "#[a-zA-Z]\+" file
```

or

```
grep -oP "#\w+" file  # please, tell me if windows have -P switch
```

## Output:

```
#Realtree
#HuntWithAnEDGE
#RealtreeEDGE
#DeerHunting
```

Answer (score 0):

The ^expr$ is needed to match the entire field, rather than just find a sub-field that matches....
For example, this matches any field that begins with a hash (#)

> if($i ~ /#[A-Z]*/)

This matches any field the begins with a hash followed by any number of A-Z, including zero but no other characters.

> if($i ~ /^#[A-Z]*$/)

This matches any field the begins with a hash followed by 1 or more A-Z, but no other characters.

> if($i ~ /^#[A-Z]*$/)